# Class for Each QStackedWidget Page

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

I am using PyQt5 and Qt-Designer to design an application.

How do I instantiate a class for each page on  QstackedWidget. I can do it in a single class, all widgets belong to the same QMainWindow. But, the issue is that the file will get too long and impracticale. How do I assign a class for each page. For example, class `I` handles all the widgets on Page `I` and class `II` handles all the widgets on Page `II`; in the QMainWindow file I can just assign an Object that represents each page.

How can I do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't "assign a class" to a page, at the very least you will add a *class instance* (generally, a QWidget) for each page. Do you want to have a more "modular" approach, using separated classes (and possibly separated files) that will then be used for the pages? Also, "the issue is that the file will get too long and impracticale": you're not trying to modify the file generated by pyuic, are you?

Comment: @musicamante  I am not modifying the pyuic files, that is not a good approach. 

"Do you want to have a more "modular" approach, using separated classes (and possibly separated files) that will then be used for the pages?" 

Yes that is exactly what I want to do. The Main Window Logic file is getting larger, it is annoying to read and debug. What I want to do is: put each page of the StackedWidget in a file, so I can easily read and modify. Assign is how I would Idescribe instance when my vocabulary is limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create multiple modules:

#### widget1.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
class Widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

#### widget2.py

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
class Widget2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

#### main.py

```py
from widget1 import Widget1
from widget2 import Widget2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setTitle("Stackked widget demo")
        self.stacked = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.stacked)
        self.widget1 = Widget1()
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.widget1)
        self.widget2 = Widget2()
        self.stacked.addWidget(self.widget2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    mainwin = MainWindow()
    mainwin.show()
    app.exec_()
```